# When I pass a struct into exist(), can I call it a 'var'?

Tags: matlab, function, struct, exists

I have made many functions where I do not always want to require input, so the first lines in many of them look like:

```
function something = thisIsMyFunction(OptionalStruct)  
   if(exist('OptionalStruct') 
      building on existing struct;  
   else
      build a new struct; 
   end
end
```

According to the docs, the exist() search goes much faster when I can pass in a type along with the option, so it will only search for that type.  I want to know if in this case (or ever) a struct is a variable and I can say:

```
if(exist('OptionalStruct', 'var')
```

Comment: didn't you try and see?

Comment: @natan Knowing any guarantees is better than trying and seeing it work by accident. That is for the general case, the case here is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use use `isstruct` to check if the variable is a structure.

```
if(exist('OptionalStruct') 
    if(isstruct(OptionalStruct))
        building on existing struct;  
else
  build a new struct; 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is assigned in a statement like

```
varName = ...;
```

is a variable and will make `exist('varName', 'var')` true.

It is totally irrelevant what type of value that variables holds or refers to.

And, seconding natan's comment:
It should take less time to test a thing like than this, than to post this question on SO.